# Four Table Join in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Okay, so I'm trying to link together four different tables, and its getting very difficult. I provided snippets of each table in the hopes you all could help out

Table 1: data

```
+--------+--------+-----------+
| charge | amount |   date    |
+--------+--------+-----------+
|    123 |  10000 | 2/10/2016 |
|    456 |  10000 | 1/28/2016 |
|    789 |  10000 | 3/30/2016 |
+--------+--------+-----------+
```

Table 2: data_metadata

```
 +--------+------------+------------+
    | charge |    key     |   value    |
    +--------+------------+------------+
    |    123 | identifier | trrkfll212 |
    |    456 | code       | test       |
    |    789 | ID         | 123xyz     |
    +--------+------------+------------+
```

Table 3: buyer

```
  +-----+-----------+----------+----------+
| id  |   date    | discount |   plan   |
+-----+-----------+----------+----------+
| ABC | 2/13/2016 | yes      | option a |
| DEF | 2/1/2016  | yes      | option a |
| GHI | 1/22/2016 | no       | option a |
+-----+-----------+----------+----------+
```

Table 4: buyer_metadata

```
+--------------+-----------+--------+
| id |    |key|              | value  |
+--------------+-----------+--------+
| ABC          | migration | TRUE   |
| DEF          | emid      | foo    |
| GHI          | ID        | 123xyz |
+--------------+-----------+--------+
```

Okay, so the tables data and data_metadata are obviously connected by the charge column.

The tables buyer and buyer_metadata are connected by the id column.

But I want to link all of them together. I'm pretty sure the way to accomplish this is through linking the metadata tables together through the common field in the "value" column (in this example: 123xyz).

Could anyone help?

Comment: All columns you want to use as "link" between tables are UNIQUE in each table ?

Comment: @Delphine I'm confused in what you're asking? The columns "charge" in data and data_metadata obviously link together. As well as the ID columns in buyer and buyer_metadata. But I need to link them ALL together.

Comment: I understand yes but I would like to know if there are "onToMany" relations between your tables. For example, is this possible that value "123" is present more than once in data table ? And so on for your 4 tables

Comment: Oh, apologies for not clarifying. Let's just assume for the purposes of this that every every value you see in charge and id are unique.

Comment: No worries !  I propose an answer in SQL language because I don't really know BigQuery and the way you are trying to use it or even language. Maybe it could give you a clue

Answer (score 1):

This might look like something like that if all "link" columns are unique :

```
SELECT * 
FROM data d
JOIN data_metadata dm ON d.charge = dm.charge
JOIN buyer_metada bm ON dm.value = bm.value
JOIN buyer b ON bm.id = b.id
```

If not, I think you'll have to use something like `GROUP BY` clause

Answer (score 1):

Let's take it in two steps, first create composite tables for `data` and `buyer`. Composite table for data:

```
SELECT data.charge, data.amount, data.date,
       data_metadata.key, data_metadata.value 
FROM [data] AS data  
JOIN (SELECT charge, key, value FROM [data_metadata]) AS data_metadata
ON data.charge = data_metadata.charge
```

And composite table for buyer:

```
SELECT buyer.id, buyer.date, buyer.discount, buyer.plan,
       buyer_metadata.key, buyer_metadata.value
FROM [buyer] AS buyer  
JOIN (SELECT key,  value FROM [buyer_metadata]) AS buyer_metadata
ON buyer.id = buyer_metadata.id
```

And then let's join the two composite tables

```
SELECT composite_data.*, composite_buyer.*
FROM (
    SELECT data.charge, data.amount, data.date,
           data_metadata.key, data_metadata.value 
    FROM [data] AS data  
    JOIN (SELECT charge, key, value FROM [data_metadata]) AS data_metadata
    ON data.charge = data_metadata.charge) AS composite_data
JOIN (
    SELECT buyer.id, buyer.date, buyer.discount, buyer.plan,
           buyer_metadata.key, buyer_metadata.value
    FROM [buyer] AS buyer  
    JOIN (SELECT key,  value FROM [buyer_metadata]) AS buyer_metadata
    ON buyer.id = buyer_metadata.id) AS composite_buyer

ON composite_data.value = composite_buyer.value
```

I haven't tested it but it's probably close.

For reference, here is the page on [BigQuery JOINs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#joins). And have you seen [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333401/joining-3-tables-in-google-bigquery)?